# Can't get select2 dropbox to work within a listbox row

Tags: html, css, jquery-select2

I have a listbox container with 3 items displayed on each row.

The first item is a label checkbox, the second is a Select2 dropbox, the third is a link to a popup.

My Fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wuz3rtv/) shows a single row taken from the listbox.

After several hours I've managed to structure the 3 items on a single row, but the Select2 dropbox shows the dropdown menu instead of the input box.

Any ideas how to get the dropbox working properly?  Also, I'm very unsure about the way I've structured the coding for each row.  Would be good to know if there's a more efficient / more robust approach.   Much appreciate any help.

```
https://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.js
https://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.css

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="First" />
  <span class="LHLabelClass">First row LH label:</span>
</label>


<span class="MiddleLabelClass">
        <select id="multipleSelectExample1" class="tester" data-placeholder="Select type" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
</span>


<span class="RHLabelClass">
<a href="#" id="POPUP1" >First RH row label</a>
</span>




$(function() {
  $("#multipleSelectExample1").select2({});
});




    * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.LHLabelClass {
  color: blue;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.MiddleLabelClass {
  width: 100px;

  margin-right: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid brown;
}

.RHLabelClass {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.select2-container-multi .select2-choices {
  outline:none;
  width: 224px!important;
  height: 27px!important;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.select2-container-multi .select2-choices .select2-search-choice{
  outline:none;
  font-size: 11px;
  background:#CEDDF0;
  color: black;
  padding: 2px 3px 2px 16px!important;
  margin-top: 5px!important;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #605D9C;
} 

 .select2-drop{
outline:none;
font-size: 12px;
color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the console of your fiddle,You are missing the jquery file here:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#multipleSelectExample").select2({});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="First" />
  <span class="LHLabelClass">First row LH label:</span>
</label>
<span class="MiddleLabelClass">
        <select id="multipleSelectExample" class="tester" data-placeholder="Select type" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
</span>

<span class="RHLabelClass">
<a href="#" id="POPUP1" >First RH row label</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Much appreciated @Suchit  kumar.  Can't believe I fell for that one!